# Executing .py script from shell script, why is $1 the magic solution?

Tags: python, shell, cygwin

I have a python script I have been trying to automatically execute within a cygwin shell script. The .py script includes a function that takes some arguments, but those arguments are defined within the .py script.

After googling for hours and trying everything under the sun, this is what ended up working:

```
python email_script.py $1
```

If I used the code below, even with full file paths and a shebang in the .py script:

```
python email_script.py
```

I would get this error meesage

```
[Errno 22] Invalid argument.exe: can't open file 'email_script.py
```

Why did $1 work?

Comment: Dont know for sure, but it might be a lineending problem in the file. I guess that the line ends with DOS lineendings and the cygwin bash sees the carriage return as part of the filename, so "email_script.py" is seen as email_script.py\r". In the second version the carriage return "belongs" to `$1`. I suggest trying to save the script with Unix-Lineendings.  The error mesage ending with `'email_script.py` (note the missing second quote) might hint that there is a linebreak after the .py and the bash thinks that character is part of the filename.

Comment: What Lars wrote. If you're working with Cygwin please make sure to use an editor for your files that saves with UNIX line ending only. If you want to see for sure you can also easily dump your file in a hex editor and see for yourself.